# SMTP Virtual Server stops on restart

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, iis, smtp

Everytime I restart my server, my SMTP Virtual Server stops. There have been a number of times where I've forgotten to start it again and I've caused a number of problems for the sites I am hosting.

Is this correct behaviour in Windows Server 2008, and is there any way in which I can stop this from happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Make sure that the SMTP service is set to "Automatic" in the Service Configuration Management Console
2. Give us the logs that contains the error messages during Windows startup.

Comment: 1) was spot on! Thank you for your help, I was looking for the startup setting in IIS itself.

Comment: It's 2020 and this service still installs with "Manual" startup. 